# Netbeans 8.2 not appearing in registry or allowing itself to be associated with files

Tags: java, file, netbeans, cmd

I have installed Netbeans 8.2 and jdk and jre 1.8.0_171. (Windows 10 OS; on a clean installation of the OS btw, just to eliminate possibility of corrupted registry keys, viruses etc).

I believe I have correctly set the system environment etc.

I created a HelloWorld file in notepad; compiled on cmd line, then when tried to run the file, I was asked as to what (default) program I wanted to use to run it.

When I went to associate netBeans I was unable to do so because it does not appear either in the menu, or in the control panel file association facility.

Even more odd, is when I went to check the registry,

Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications

netbeans was not there.....

Netbeans itself btw runs and works absolutely fine, so I am rather baffled by this....

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a Java application from the command line in Windows then you should be using **java.exe** to run it. NetBeans is an IDE, and while it does provide functionality to allow Java to be run internally (i.e From within NetBeans), that is very different to using NetBeans directly to run a Java application.

Furthermore, NetBeans does not use the Windows Registry for [application registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx), which is why you cannot associate NetBeans with any file type. Just because NetBeans can be installed as a Windows application does not mean that it is required to implement all the possible functionality of a Windows Application, such as file association.

It's also worth noting that [the beta release of NetBeans 9](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90-beta.html#_downloading) is only provided as a zip file, and its installation consists of nothing more than unzipping the dowloaded file to a folder, so it definitely does not use the Windows Registry.